# add attributes to a <td> element of a table on the fly

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css, gridview

I'm using theme from devexpress (moderno) and I use a GridView, but I wanna use a jQuery that hidden columns (footable), but in the configuration of my gridview I just configured the data-columns, when the page is running and the gridview it's full of data, the table is generated and the td as well. But, I wanna add some attributes to the `<td>` tag (`<td data-hidden="all" >`)

Is there a way to do this with CSS??

Comment: You want CSS (which tells a browser how to display elements) to make a content change to the HTML elements/element attributes?  That can not be done.

Comment: adding attribute can be done only with script (either pure javascript or jQuery)

Comment: Fist of all, tnks for the corrections, if I use js or jquery, can you tell me an example? Cos' I'm trying to edit the <td> code in Chrome, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could set this with ASP.NET.

```
  void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { 
    GridView1.RowCreated += new GridViewRowEventHandler(GridView1_RowCreated);
  }

  void GridView1_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes["data-hidden"] = "all";
        }
    }
  }
```

Or with jQuery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>")
       .find("tr:first td")
           .each(function(){
               $(this).data("hidden", "all");
           });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Tnks, I will trying this.